# Keyboard Shortcut to reach to Taskbar Folder Links

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

What is the `shortest` keyboard shortcut for browsing through the Folder Links in Taskbar in `Windows 7`. I have tried my best to find answers from the existing questions, but could not come up with a faster shortcut.

Here is an example of Folder Links on Taskbar.

[image]

Folder toolbar can be created by right clicking on Taskbar and `New Toolbar`.

[image]

#### What I have tried

- `ctrl + b` - it only enables navigating through notifications.
- Press `Window` + `Escape` + `Tab` (multiple tabs) to reach to the folder links. While this works OK, I wish there is a better way to enable `Folder Links` navigation?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You mean the minimized windows on Taskbar?

Comment: `Windows Key` + `Tab` also `Alt` + `Tab` keep pressing `Windows Key` and press then release `Tab` it will take you from one folder to another (the minimized one) when you see the needed one release both keys (the same with `Alt` + `Tab`

Comment: @yass, No, I am not looking to minimize windows or switch between folders. I am aware of `alt + tab`. What I am looking is an easy way to navigate to Folder Links on Task Bar. I added the picture to better describe my question.

Comment: You need `Windows Key` + the number of the item (0 Start Menu) the first Icon next to start is 1

Comment: In your picture `Windows Key` + `1` to open The Folder

Comment: @yass, I added the description in the question. I am talking about the folder toolbar on the right hand side of taskbar. `Window + 0-9` does not work for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win+T focuses the first item in the task bar, then use tab.